# How to listen to Seekbar thumb onClick events?

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, seekbar, android-seekbar

I would like to register a clickable event on the seekbar's thumb in order to trigger an event when the user has cliked it. Is it possible?Any ideas?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Override the OnTouchListener for the seekbar and only process the movement on the thumb when the MotionEvent is a move event.

event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE

Please refer the https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar

Comment: But this access to the entire Seekbar onclick event I want to get seekbar's thumb onclick